# Is restart required after changing operating system configuration and tuning

Tags: performance, cassandra, linux-kernel, operating-system, disk

I have a cassandra cluster where I recently added two new nodes . Looking at the stats I observed that disk I/O in these newly added machines is way higher than the already present machines . 
On checking I found that the read_ahead_kb OS configuration on these machines is 4096 whereas other machines it is 4 .

I changed the value but the disk I/O is still same . Do we need to restart the machines for these OS configuration changes to take effect ?

Also if there is any other setting I need to look at .

Answer (score 1, accepted):

It depends how you set the readahead value. The following command will set the readahead for `/dev/sda` to 4kb, and will take effect immediately (no reboot necessary):

`sudo blockdev --setra 4 /dev/sda`

I recommend configuring a udev rule (as described [here](http://unix.stackexchange.com/a/71409/36574)), as otherwise the change will be lost after a reboot.

Read ahead is one of the most important performance tweaks regarding disk I/O & throughput. Some other things that are important for read performance:

- ensure you have plenty of free RAM for the OS page cache
- disable swap
- use SSDs over spinning disks, especially if you have a read-heavy workload

This guide is a few years old, but many of the OS tuning & hardware recommendations still apply to Cassandra 3.x:
https://tobert.github.io/pages/als-cassandra-21-tuning-guide.html